# What is the syntax for date functions in openquery - OleDB through SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oledb, openquery, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to dynamically pass a date function in an openquery on SQL Server.  My SQL Server is connected to and OleDB Oracle database.

When I run my query using an Oracle based date function, my query runs, but returns no data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY( [SMA], 'SELECT B.SQL_DATE
                        FROM DIM_DATE B
                        WHERE B.SQL_DATE = current_DATE');
```

When I run that query using a SQL Server based date function I get the following error message:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([SMA], 'SELECT B.SQL_DATE
                       FROM DIM_DATE B
                       WHERE B.SQL_DATE = ''GETDATE()''');
```

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "SMA" returned message "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0".

I think I'm supposed to be using SQL Server based syntax (as opposed to Oracle syntax), but not sure how the current_DATE statement is even able to run?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The 'GETDATE()' is being replaced by the SQL Server parser's date representation because the evaluation is not in the string literal, whereas, current_DATE is being sent over the wire to the connected server and being parsed as sql there. Check your locale and make sure the date values align. You can force a specific date value and it sounds like that is what you need to do here.

Comment: So part of the problem is the date field I am referencing is a timestamp.  If I am querying the database outside of the open query I get get this to work: SELECT B.SQL_DATE

       FROM  [SMA]..[SMA].[DIM_DATE] B

       WHERE B.SQL_DATE = Convert(date, GETDATE());
However, I can't see to figure out what set of ticks I need to use, or if it is even possible to pass that function through openquery.

Answer (score 2):

You use the syntax that your target database supports, so in this case you use Oracle syntax.

GetDate() equivalent is SYSDATE. This contains a time so you can remove the time by speciying TRUNC(SYSDATE). For date literals you would need to specify a TO_DATE() function, E.g. TO_DATE('31-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')

It gets messy when using OpenQuery as date literals would have to be double single quotes, i.e. TO_DATE(''31-DEC-2016'',''DD-MON-YYYY'')

Comment: BOOM!  You are the best!  that did the trick.  It also helped me to understand philosophically how to better understand what functions to use through open query.  I owe stack overflow some answers to some questions when I get a minute!!

Comment: @BobbyJobsite - You could also [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) this answer.